# Box-sizing, why height > 100%?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the markup for a simple panel. The structure is below. The `<div>` with "transcluded" in it should fill its parent container `<div>`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-title">title</div>
    <div class="container-body">
        transcluded
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see (in http://jsfiddle.net/kAk9Z/), the "transcluded" body extends beyond its container instead of filling only.

How can I get the container to stay its size while having the "transcluded" `<div>` fill in the remaining space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a `box-sizing` issue, when you declare height 100% it is referred to the height of the parent element, which already contains a div so the sum of the heights of the `.container`'s children is > 100.

A solution can be switch the container body to `position: absolute`, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kAk9Z/2/

```
.container {
    width: 640px; 
    height: 480px; 
    background-color: #dededd; 
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.container-body {
    background-color: white; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set you're height on the inner body div. That way it will determine the height of your container div, and you get the result you want. You could even go for a min-height and have it grow when the content requiers it. Something like this:

```
.container {
    width: 640px; 
    background-color: #dededd; 
    padding: 4px;
}

.container-body {
    background-color: white; 
    height: 100%; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 460px; 
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kAk9Z/4/